# Increase the setTimeout for this MDL jquery snackbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, snackbar

Increase the setTimeout of the jquery snackbar (preferably by editing the last line of the script).

```
<div id="snackbar" class="mdl-js-snackbar mdl-snackbar"><br>
<div class="mdl-snackbar__text"></div>`<br>
<button class="mdl-snackbar__action" type="button"></button>
</div>
<script>
(function(){
  var snackbarContainer = document.querySelector('#snackbar');
  var data = { message: 'Incorrect Username/Password. Check if your account exists.'};
   snackbarContainer.MaterialSnackbar.showSnackbar(data);
`});
function r(f){ /in/.test(document.readyState)?setTimeout('r('+f+')',9):f()}`<br>
`</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

That last line is [smallest DOM Ready ever](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=smallest%20domready%20ever), I can't make snackbar last longer just by changing it. But looks like in api for snackbar, adding timeout property to data variable will solve our problem.

```
    var data = {
      message: 'Button color changed.',
      timeout: 6000
   }
```

Checkout demo here https://codepen.io/theami_mj/pen/EXOgjz/#code-area

Answer (score 0):

For the settimeout function codelike this

```
setTimeout(function (f) {
    r(f);
}, 9);
```

I your case Do like this

```
function r(f){
    /in/.test(document.readyState)?setTimeout(function (f) {r(f);},9):f();
}
```

Comment: Okay there are other issues.But tell me what you want to do?

Comment: This is a snackbar, which I'm using to display content. But it displays for only 3-4 seconds, i want it to be displayed for 6 seconds.

Comment: Okay then what is `'r('+f+')` and `f()` ?those are functions or any thing else?